# Can't show the data from the file properly in C program

Tags: c, file-io, binaryfiles, randomaccessfile

I faced a little problem right now which is the C program can't print the result on the screen properly. Even the program can write input from the user and print it into Notepad.
The type of file used is random access file and I need to write data into a binary file named toyota.txt
Anyone can teach me what is the problem there? Thank you so much!

```
/*program 1: write the data into file toyota.txt*/

#include<stdio.h>

struct vehicledata{
    char vnum[100];
    int cnum;
    float f50[100];
    float f100[100];
    float f200[100];
    float f400[100];
    float f800[100];
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    struct vehicledata toyota;
    if((fptr = fopen("toyota.txt","wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! File fail opened!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This program can create a text file named toyota.txt \n");
        printf("and save the value of car noise level(dB) with\n different frequency and vehicle numbers into file\n\n");
        printf("Enter car number(1 to 10, enter 0 to end input)\n");
        printf("? ");
        scanf("%d", &toyota.cnum);

        while (toyota.cnum != 0)
        {
            printf("\nEnter Vehicle and car noise level(dB) at 50Hz, 100Hz, 200Hz, 400Hz and 800Hz\n");
            printf("? ");
            scanf("%s %f %f %f %f %f", toyota.vnum, &toyota.f50, &toyota.f100, &toyota.f200, &toyota.f400, &toyota.f800);
            fseek(fptr, (toyota.cnum - 1) * sizeof(struct vehicledata), SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(&toyota, sizeof(struct vehicledata), 1, fptr);
            printf("\nEnter car number (1 to 100, 0 to end input) \n");
            scanf("%d", &toyota.cnum);
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

```
/*program 2 : reads the data from the file toyota.txt and find
the car that emanates the minimum noise at 200Hz*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vehicledata{
    char vnum[100];
    int cnum;
    float f50[100];
    float f100[100];
    float f200[100];
    float f400[100];
    float f800[100];
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    struct vehicledata toyota;
    if ((fptr = fopen("toyota.txt","rb")) == NULL)//open and read data in the file
    {
        printf("Error! File fail opened!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This program can read and display the data from the toyota.txt\n and find car that have minimum noise in 200Hz\n\n");
        printf("\nThe information in the toyota.txt are shown at below:\n");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tCar Noise Level(dB)\t\t\t");
        printf("\n=======================================================================\n");
        printf("%s\t\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n","Vehicle Number","50Hz","100Hz","200Hz","400Hz","800Hz");
        printf("=======================================================================\n");
        while(!feof(fptr))
        {
            fread(&toyota, sizeof(struct vehicledata), 1, fptr);
            if(toyota.cnum != 0)
            {
                printf("%s\t\t\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f", toyota.vnum, toyota.f50, toyota.f100, toyota.f200, toyota.f400, toyota.f800);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: The output]

[image: The data that need to entered]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major problem with the implementation is that the `vehicledata` structure is wrong.

Try

```
struct vehicledata {
    char vnum[100];
    int cnum;
    float f50;
    float f100;
    float f200;
    float f400;
    float f800;
};
```

and it will work a lot easier.

You don't want to collect 500 (5 * 100) different freqeuncey data for each vehicle it seems.